# MudBlazor DataGrid NoRecordsContent

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor

Can somebody help me how I can give parameter to `NoRecordsContent` parameter of DataGrid, please. I would like stylized text display when there's no data to be displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoRecordsContent` is a `RenderFragment` parameter. You use it like this:

```
<MudDataGrid ...>
    ...
    <NoRecordsContent>
        No data
    </NoRecordsContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

You can put any html content (or other Blazor components) inside `<NoRecordsContent></NoRecordsContent>`: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkwIudENKnGKnhrI